# Passing combobox value into SQL query in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a combobox in a form, and I want the text of the combobox to be passed into a query.

My query is:

```
select..from..where something=[Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup]
```

The form's name is `Enter Data` and the combobox's name is `comboCup`. Should i do this:

```
[Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup]![text]
```

or this?

```
[Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup]![value]
```

Comment: Say more about the source for the Combo Box.  Is it 1 column, or more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup].

As @Remou has said, the .Text property of an Access control is available only when the control has the focus.

The .Value property is redundant, as it's the default property of all Access controls, so these two are equivalent:

```
  [Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup]
  [Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup].Value
```

(note also that properties like .Text and .Value are separated by the dot operator and not the bang, which delineates collections)

One issue that can be of concern is if you want to use the value of the combo box in the SELECT statement of an APPEND query. In that case, you would be advised to declare the combo box as a parameter in your saved query. If you do not, it can cause the row to not be inserted, whereas if you declare the parameter, it will resolve to the Null that is the value in the referenced combo box.

Comment: im sorry can you explain what do you mean by append query?

Comment: INSERT INTO MyTable ( MyField ) Values ( [Forms]![Enter Data]![comboCup] ). That will work better if you define the form control as a parameter.

Comment: It's not easy to find this answer just by Google without already knowing what you are looking for, and searching the current Access helpfiles is a nightmare. That this answer is now on the first page of Google for my search is a testament to how useful it is.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Text is only available when the control has the focus. The value of comboCup is the bound column. Ensure that your query is looking for that value, otherwise you will need to refer to the column property of the combo.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim comboBoxText As String 

comboBoxText = Me.YourComboboxName.Column(1)
```

Note: Combobox column is 1 based array

Answer (score 0):

If you'll work it in the Form module, you can do something like this (pseudo code only):

```
Event comboCup_afterUpdate()
    strCup = Me!comboCup
    strSQL = "SELECT ... etc ... ='" & strCup & "'"
End Sub
```

If in a different module, then still use variables as shown above; in that case however, your syntax for identifying the field in the form needs a lot of work.  i can tell you more about that if this all makes sense so far.

Comment: What is going to happen to strSQL next?

Comment: How does this answer relate to "passing the text of the combo box into a query"?