# SQL criteria set to form

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have searched for this question and though I found the answer but I cant get it to work

This is the Link I followed:

[passing combobox value into sql query MS ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845087/passing-combobox-value-into-sql-query-ms-access)

Here is my SQL code im using, but when I run it nothing comes up, I have a Product_ID selected in the combo box before I run it but there is still nothing showing up.

```
SELECT [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Element
  FROM [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only]
 WHERE  ((
                "[1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Product_ID" = [Forms]![New Report]!
                [cbProduct_ID]
        ));
```

I have made sure the combo box is called cbProduct_ID and the form is called New Report.

[1 Cut Wire & Cable Only] is the name of the table

I am doing any thing in particle wrong ?

Comment: Sorry .. but what is [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Element mean ?

Comment: [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only] is the table and Element is the name of the coloum it is just a Description of the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the double quotes, and close up the whitespace.

```
SELECT [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Element
  FROM [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only]
 WHERE  (
           [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Product_ID = [Forms]![New Report]![cbProduct_ID]
        );
```

Comment: thank you, quite embarrasing how simple the answer is, I though I tryed every variant of the sql but obvisouly not, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
SELECT Element FROM [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only] WHERE [1 Cut Wire & Cable Only].Product_ID
= [Forms]![New Report]![cbProduct_ID]
```